# "Such as" or "such as that"?

Tags: such

Which of the two sentences is more grammatically correct? The sentence is following a paragraph that describes the narrators relationship with his neighbor.

1. Developing strong relationships such as with my neighbor is important to me.
2. Developing strong relationships such as that with my neighbor is important to me.

Answer (score -1):

Both are grammatical, but the second, with the demonstrative pronoun, indicates that a strong relationship already exists, while the first only indicates that it is desired.